# Scalar valued function not found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made the following scalar valued function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CountCustomers] 
(
    @Name varchar
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result int

    SET @Result = 1
    RETURN @Result

END
```

But when I am calling it as

```
SELECT dbo.CountCustomers
```

I am not able to do it.

Comment: Don't you pass the `@Name`?? like `SELECT dbo.CountCustomers('NAME')`

Comment: Please post the complete error message the next time: `The multi-part identifier "dbo.CountCustomers" could not be bound.`

Answer (score 2):

You defined a parameter for your function (`@Name`), so call the function with a value for that parameter:

```
SELECT dbo.CountCustomers('foo')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a value into your function such as this:

```
SELECT dbo.CountCustomers('name')
```

The reason is you have @Name varchar as a parameter.

You can also call it like this:

```
DECLARE @Count INT
SET @Count = dbo.CountCustomers('name')
SELECT @Count
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parentheses to call the function, and then add in one parameter in order for it to work.

```
SELECT dbo.CountCustomers('hello world')
```